# jQuery image swap show – IE8 bug?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, slideshow

As part of a Wordpress site for an artist, I made a simple jQuery image swap cycle to use on each individual custom post. Essentially, just a large image with a photo credit below it, and a set of seven thumbnails below that to show different views of the art piece. Clicking on each thumbnail swaps out the current large image for the href in the thumbnail as well as swapping out the photo credit. The photo credit uses a hidden div with .hideText class inside of each thumbnail which contains the correlating photographer's name, supplied by PHP.

All works correctly in Firefox, Chrome, Opera, and IE > 8. In IE8, on first load each image can be clicked in sequence to produce the corresponding large image, but after clicking the seventh thumbnail or clicking out of straight numeric sequence results in the large image not showing, although the href is still correct. Note: using jQuery 1.8.2 and Modernizr 2.6.2.

Beyond the IE8 bug, there are three other annoyances I suppose worth mentioning. 1) Using .load() produces slow load times until the images are cached. I guess I should have used a preloader, but not sure how to make that work with this setup. 2) And because the large images load slowly, the absolutely positioned photo credit sometimes shows first in the wrong place until the img has loaded. Ideally the jQuery photo credit block would be chained to follow the image load code to avoid that; I tried to do that using anonymous functions, but couldn't get it to work, so the .delay() is a hackish and unreliable alternative. 3) On click, the #artWrap background spinner should be added before the old image is hidden and removed after the new one is faded in, but it doesn't work consistently.

Given the unexpected time investment, in retrospect I probably would have used a WP image gallery plugin instead, but I wanted to learn about this stuff. Any suggestions welcome!

**Pertinent jQuery:**

```
$('.thumbnail').live("click", function() {

$('#artWrap').css('background-image', "url('../img/ajax-loader-48-48.gif')");
$('#artLarge').hide();

var i = $('<img />').attr('src',this.href).load(function() {
    $('#artLarge').attr('src', i.attr('src'));
    $('#artLarge').fadeIn(200);     
    $('#artWrap').css('background-image', 'none');
});

if ( $(this).find('.hideText').is(':empty') ) {
    $('#photoCredit').hide().empty();
} else {
    $('#photoCredit').hide().empty();
    var newCredit = $(this).find('.hideCredit').html();
    $('#photoCredit').html(newCredit).delay(600).fadeIn(200);
}

return false;

});
```

...

**Basic div structure:**

```
<div id="artShow">  

    <div id="artWrap" >

        <div id="artImage">
            <img id="artLarge" src="../uploads/EXAMPLE_1-LG.jpg">
        </div><!-- #artImage -->

        <div id="photoCredit">
            Photo: Example 1 Photographer
        </div><!-- .artCredit -->

    </div><!-- #artWrap -->

    <div id="artThumbs" class="clearfix">

        <div id="thumb1" class="thumb">
            <a href="../uploads/EXAMPLE_1-LG.jpg" class="thumbnail nofancybox"><!-- large image link goes in href here -->
                <img src="../uploads/EXAMPLE_1-SM.jpg" width="72" height="72" ><!-- small image -->
            </a>
            <div class="hideCredit">Photo: Example 1 Photographer</div>

        </div><!-- #thumb1 -->

        <div id="thumb2" class="thumb">
            <a href="../uploads/EXAMPLE_2-LG.jpg" class="thumbnail nofancybox">
                <img src="../uploads/EXAMPLE_2-SM.jpg" width="72" height="72" >
            </a>
        <div class="hideCredit">Photo: Example 2 Photographer</div>

        </div><!-- #thumb2 -->

        <div id="thumb3" class="thumb"> ... ETC ... </div>
        <div id="thumb4" class="thumb"> ... ETC ... </div>
        <div id="thumb5" class="thumb"> ... ETC ... </div>
        <div id="thumb6" class="thumb"> ... ETC ... </div>
        <div id="thumb7" class="thumb"> ... ETC ... </div>

    </div><!-- #artThumbs -->

</div><!-- #artShow -->
```

...

**Pertinent CSS:**

```
/* Content shell for whole image swap show */
#artShow { float: right; position: relative; width: 630px; min-height: 570px; }

/* wrap for both image and photo credit */
#artWrap { float: left; position: relative; background: url('../img/ajax-loader-48-48.gif') center center no-repeat; }

/* wrapper for large image */
#artImage { min-height: 456px; margin-bottom: 19px; line-height: 0;  /* lh adjusts photo credit */ }

/* ID attached to large img */
#artLarge { }  

/* photo credit below artImage */
#photoCredit { 
position: absolute;
right: 0;
bottom: -5px;
height: 16px;
padding-top: 3px;
width: 100%;
text-align: right;
}

#artThumbs { position: absolute; top: 492px; left: 0; width: 651px; height: 72px; }

.thumb { float: left; margin-right: 21px; width: 72px; height: 72px; background-color: #c9c9c9; }

.thumbnail { display: block; width: 72px; height: 72px; }
```

Comment: are there any errors in the browser console?

Comment: @Spudley None that seem to apply here. Using FF, the only JS one is for audio in a separate part of the page. I think the only relevant CSS ones are for the unfound background spinner. Have tried using the Windows Dev Tools in IE8 as well as IE9 w/IE8 compatibility mode to see if they come up with different errors, but not throwing any that I can tell (but I'm unfamiliar with those consoles). You can check the behavior on staging site here: http://alisonmoritsugu.com/amwp/work/log-series/red-cabbage/

Answer (score 0):

After a little bit of debugging with the staging URL you provided, I think I can see what the problem is for you.

It would seem that your `.load()` function for the image (line 57 of AM_main.js) is only being called the first time the image is loaded. If the same image is clicked a second time, the `load()` function is not called.

This is because the image has already been loaded and is thus in the browser cache when you come to load it again. What is happening here is that the `load` event *is* firing, but because the image is already in cache it is firing *immediately* when the `src` attribute is set.

The key here is the word *immediately*. The `load` event is fired and finished before jQuery gets to the next bit of the code... which is where you specify the function you want the `load` event to call. The `load()` function is defined after the event `load` has already happened.

So the solution here is to change the order of your jQuery code, such that the load event function is defined before you specify the `src` attribute. This is fairly trivial; it just needs a slight re-arranging of your existing code, like so:

```
var i = $('<img />').load(function() {
    ....
}).attr('src',this.href);
```

Hopefully, that should solve the problem for you.

An alternative solution would be to avoid re-creating a new `<img>` element every time you run the click event. If you had a single `<img>` element that was re-used each time, the load even would always already be in place when the `src` was set, so the issue described above wouldn't occur; even if the event did fire immediately, that would be fine because the event handler function is already there.

This solution would also give you a small performance benefit, from not having to repeatedly create the `<img>` element.

The down-side, of course, is that it would be a bigger code change than the other solution above. But it wouldn't be a huge amount of work, so perhaps you should give it a try.

Whichever solution you go with, I hope that helps.

Comment: This looked like a good idea, but the image's src is called within the function [as i.attr('src')] so I don't think the attr() can come after the function. I did try this change anyway, and it didn't (oddly to me) affect any other browser, but IE8 threw a "i is null or not an object" error, which is what I would have expected and IE8's behavior didn't otherwise change. I tried adding a 100ms delay after the attr() to see if that might also work, but it didn't. I think you've nailed the problem though, I just need to think it through a bit more. Thanks!

Comment: @boomturn -- the `attr()` *can* come after the function. This is because the function is an event handler: it isn't called when it is defined; it's called when the relevant event occurs. In this case, that event is `load`, which happens when the `src` value changes and the new image has been loaded into the element. The code I gave you should work; could you provide an example that creates the error you described?

Comment: OK, I've edited the script so per your answer the attr() is again after the .load() function on staging server. What happens with this in cleared-cache IE8 is that clicking unloaded thumbnails in 1-2-3... order displays img correctly through img 7. If thumbnail 1 is then clicked, img 1 loads correctly at cached speed, but no other image will load after that. If at any point any _other_ previously loaded image has thumbnail clicked, no image will load. Hope that's clear!

Comment: It turns out this is a common problem. See: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/fixing-load-in-ie-for-cached-images/  Some people there use your solution of adding attr() after and it works for them. The other option mentioned is to append the src URL with "?" + new Date().getTime() to force an image load on every click. I've tested this and it works but of course loses the benefits of caching in every other browser. Given existing load performance issues, that's not a great option for me although I guess worst-case I'll load a separate script to do that in IE8.